# How can I complete installation after a reboot?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer

I'm using a Visual Studio Deployment project in VS2010 to install/upgrade my application, and on Windows 2003 and older it seems like it refuses to stop the service before attempting the upgrade.  As a result, it requires a reboot after the installation finishes.  Here's a snip from the msiexec log where I have `program.exe` running under the old service and I'm trying to install `program.exe` as part of the upgrade:

```
MSI (s) (70:64) [12:00:34:448]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
MSI (s) (70:64) [12:00:34:682]: 1 application(s) had been reported to have files in use.
Info 1603. The file C:\Program Files\company\program.exe is being held in use by the following process: Name: program, Id: 712, Window Title: '(not determined yet)'.  Close that application and retry.
MSI (c) (60:BC) [12:00:34:682]: File In Use: -program- Window could not be found.  Process ID: 712
MSI (c) (60:BC) [12:00:34:682]: No window with title could be found for FilesInUse
MSI (s) (70:64) [12:00:34:682]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
MSI (s) (70:64) [12:00:34:682]: Doing action: InstallInitialize
Action ended 12:00:34: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
```

On reboot the software appears to be installed but the files that were in use previously were not re-installed, and the service has not been installed.  The shortcut I drop on the Desktop acts as an advertised shortcut - double-clicking it will force MSI to see that the installation is incomplete and it repairs successfully.

BUT, some users may be doing this upgrade without logging back in (to a web server for instance), and I'd like to either:

1. Complete the installation without requiring a reboot, or
2. Reboot and complete the installation automatically prior to user login.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Running `msiexec /i <pkg.msi> /norestart` - this doesn't help, and if I try to use the shortcut prior to restarting, it attempts to repair the install and fails.
2. Disabling advertised shortcuts by setting the property `DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1` - this doesn't work either, because then the target opens but the install still isn't complete so it won't run properly.  The `msiexec /f <pkg.msi>` can still be used to repair the install.
3. Adding a `RunOnce` key to the registry at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce` to invoke the repair operation to finish the install - this didn't seem to run, but it worked if I ran it at the command line so I'm not sure what the issue is here.  The value of the string I added to RunServicesOnce using the installer is `[SystemFolder]\msiexec.exe /f [ProductCode] /qn`, which seems to evaluate correctly to `C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /f {my code} /qn`.
4. Editing the .msi with Orca to stop the service (via the ServiceControl table) so that the file is not in use - this doesn't work because it doesn't seem to stop the service until after it has evaluated whether or not the file is held.

I think I'm lost and I hope I'm missing something obvious.  Set me straight.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a custom action to invoke ServiceController class and stop the service programatically?

Comment: Ah yeah, I tried that too but those are invoked too late - on older targets (similarly with the ServiceControl table issue in 4 above) the Install custom actions don't run until after the installer has checked to see if the file is in use.

Comment: You can set the custom action to run OnBeforeInstall event. Wouldn't it solve the problem?

Comment: I made the custom action an installer class and overrode the `OnBeforeInstall` method - is that what you mean?  It didn't stop it prior to the install.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean with OnBeforeInstall. If it didn't work, then you'll have to look at your service code, and why it's so busy it can't respond to the stop command in time. The problem is not in the installer, but in the unresponsive service.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the punch line there is that the old version is already out in the wild.  Interestingly, even if I stop the service successfully and then start the upgrade, it still only advertises the install - nothing happens until I repair or run the shortcut I drop on the Desktop.